# Something somewhere preventing only one site (connect.media, doesn't matter if FQDN is used or not) from loading in IE on all computers

Tags: networking, firewall, internet-explorer

Unless I'm connected to a hotspot or using a proxy site, at which point the site loads in IE with no issues. This first made me think this was a network-wide issue, until I tested in Chrome and Firefox (even tested from the DC) and it loaded with no issues in Chrome and Firefox but still did not load in IE.

We utilize Spectrum MRS, so at that point I bypassed ISP's equipment and plugged my laptop directly into the demarc, website loaded in IE with no issues, so I contacted ISP and have been going back and forth with ISP for some time now and they have not been able to find anything (understandably so, from my perspective, just feel like I've ruled out everything on our end).

Just curious if anyone has enough experience with IE to know if the firewall could be interfering with a setting? I've reset all IE settings but that's as far as my knowledge goes with IE. Even downgraded to IE 8, same results. Have searched various IE settings but cannot find anything remotely close to this issue. Sorry if this seems convoluted, the issue alone is starting to make my head spin!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Your question is hard to read.  Please Edit it and introduce paragraphs with double-newlines.  Please include the precise URL you're trying to visit.

Comment: If the problem doesn't happen from the demarc, how is this the ISP's problem? Does the ISP own/manage your CPE? Have you tried taking concurrent packet traces on both sides of the box that seems to be blocking this, to compare how IE's packets look when they go into the box with how they come out?

Comment: connect.media and

https://www.connect.media = https : // www . connect . media

The equipment is managed by the ISP, have not taken packet captures while connected to the demarc, will get to that this evening since I will have to take the network down.

Comment: After looking through the source code, my money is on ads the site is hosting, which are causing the site to get blocked. My next question would be why would this only be affected on IE, regardless of the different versions?

Answer (score 0):

This case has been solved after working with multiple levels of support with ISP, finally able to confirm that it was indeed embedded code on the page that was calling ads that was causing the page to be blocked; after allowing the URLS, site works fine now in IE. Although, I don't see how this was only affecting IE since there doesn't even seem to be a built-in ad blocker.

Comment: If you were trying this at work, it may be possible your IT have set up some sort of "bad stuff" filter for the internet. This is how the network where I work is set up - known ad servers and sketchy IPs are blocked automagically. Not sure why this would only affect IE though, so that's probably not what caused it. Just a thought.

Comment: I appreciate any and all feedback as I like to know why things happen and not just fix things and move on. We do actively block Google Ad Services, but this turned out to be an issue with OneTag, which I had never heard of until this issue, although the ISP claimed not to be blocking anything else until they actually saw this was getting blocked during a packet capture, so not exactly sure what happened on their end or why it would only affect IE. Assuming it had something to do with Javascript though as that is what the errors were pointing to, just couldn't even begin to guess why.